# Extend volume of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning

I use Ubuntu 20.04 for nextcloud server, the server physical HD is around 2TB but the volume group size just is 200GB, how can we extend to increase volume group size? Thanks.

1.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The partition size cannot be modified while it is in use, so you'll need to boot from a Live USB or Live DVD to do this. That said, it's not too difficult to do:

0. Make a backup of your important files (you *do* backup your files ... right?)
1. Boot to a Live USB or Live DVD and choose "Try Ubuntu"
2. Load GParted
3. Resize the Logical Volume (this would appear to be above the partition)
   ⇢ Right Click ⇢ Resize ⇢ Follow instructions
4. Resize the partition
   ⇢ Right Click ⇢ Resize ⇢ Follow instructions
5. Click "Apply"

Once everything is done, reboot. Be sure to remove the USB stick or DVD when the system tells you it's safe to do so.

Comment: Thanks Matigo, i will try it...

Comment: Can I use current gparted on exiting Ubuntu instead of Live USB(Ubuntu)?

Comment: You cannot modify any partitions while they are active. If you can unmount the partition, then you can expand the logical volume followed by the partition. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Many thanks your advise :)